# If/when in this example?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, ambiguity

I am struggling with understanding when I can use if/when interchangeably. The situation is like this, I meet my friend outside who is heading to the dentist.
I say (in that situation, knowing he is about to see the dentist in a while):

> If you are going to the dentist, you should brush your teeth.

But I can say that in general:

> Children, if you are going to the dentist, you should brush your
>   teeth.

Should it not be better/needed to use 'when' in any of these sentences? I still feel like 'if' means 'maybe it is going to happen' while 'when' 'it is going to happen at some point'.

Comment: I feel if~should and when~must or _before going to the dentist you should brush your teeth_

Comment: Well but isn't one for general situations (like saying) and one for (one-off situations)? I would say "When" implies general knowledge, statement that is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific context, *if* and *when* actually have slightly different connotations. As Kristen Ramos said, both are substantially correct; your meaning will be understood in either case. That said, the *if*-version is the preferred way to give advice about a specific, imminent situation.

> If you are going to the dentist, you should brush your teeth.

means something like

> If you are going to the dentist [right now, as I think you are], you should brush your teeth.

Here, the scope of the *if* (the ‘right now’) is understood from context. You don't mean (and a native speaker wouldn't mistake you as meaning) ‘if you're *ever* going to the dentist.’ In contrast,

> When you are going to the dentist, you should brush your teeth.

is open to at least two interpretations, both of which are unnecessarily general for your situation:

> 1) When you are going to the dentist [whenever that happens to be], you should brush your teeth.
>   2) Whenever one is going to the dentist, one should brush one's teeth.

*When* is very frequently used in this second sense, to describe a general rule or principle. This means that

> Children, when you are going to the dentist, you should brush your teeth.

is the preferred form for your second example, because the speaker is dispensing broad advice not tied to a particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, in this particular instance if/when are interchangeable. It is up to you how you would like to use them. You **are** correct. "If" implies it could happen, while "when" means that it is going to happen. For this type of sentence there isn't a word structure rule that states you **have** to use one or the other. It's a matter of preference for what you want to say.

Comment: So if a friend tells me on the street "I am going to the dentist" I can say "When you are going to the dentist, you should brush your teeth"? And it is the same as with "If"?