# What is the meaning of the statement "Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened."?

Tags: ambiguity, conditionals

Does it mean:

> **1.** If a tiger/lion is hungry or threatened, it certainly WILL attack.

or does it mean:

> **2.** A tiger/lion will attack ONLY if it is hungry or threatened (and never otherwise).

I want to know because the answer to this question will decide how I answer the following question on my test:

> Which one of the first order predicate calculus statements given below
> correctly expresses the following English statement?
>
> *"Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened."*
>
> A. ∀x[(tiger(x)∧lion(x))→(hungry(x)∨threatened(x))→attacks(x)]
>
> B. ∀x[(tiger(x)∨lion(x))→(hungry(x)∨threatened(x))∧attacks(x)]
>
> C. ∀x[(tiger(x)∨lion(x))→attacks(x)→(hungry(x)∨threatened(x))]
>
> D. ∀x[(tiger(x)∨lion(x))→(hungry(x)∨threatened(x))→attacks(x)]

I'd select option D. if **1.** was the correct meaning and option C. if **2.** was.

Which one is the correct meaning?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English as much as one or more other disciplines.

Comment: I can explain what the symbols in the options stand for. The options are basically statements of implication. For example, option C. reads "For all x, if (x is a tiger) OR (x is a lion), THEN, if x attacks, THEN x must be hungry OR threatened"

Comment: None of them are correct. These are Generic sentences; consider that both the noun phrases and the verb phrases are generic here -- this is second-order quantification. Further, generic verb phrases don't use the familiar logical quantifiers -- consider _Bill walks to work_ -- is it false if somebody gave him a ride one day? How about once a month? Once a week? Or consider _That dog bites_ -- how many bites are we talking about here; and what are we quantifying over? For generic noun phrases, see [this discussion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: If those are the only choices, I'd go with D; but of course in normal English usage sentences like these do not correspond to strict predicate-calculus interpretations.

Comment: @JohnLawler Going by the link that you provided (thanks), the sentence in question is Plural Generic which means it is vague (things are 'likely') and not a definite statement of fact. Would you say the test question is ill-formed?

Comment: Of course it's ill-formed; it assumes that English is structured the same way as predicate calculus, which is ridiculous. [Logic is just a stick-figure representation of semantics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), and can't capture anything with the slightest degree of continuity in it, which is most of natural language. Statements about "truth" are really statements about personal judgements of probability, and humans know this. So quantifiers don't really help.

Comment: I think this question is entirely on-topic. It is about the subtle implications of particular syntax (for 'if') and how that may or may not be captured by logical (stipulated mathematical) forms.

Comment: @Hellion Can you point out what is wrong with this line of thinking - If the author meant to say that a tiger or lion will certainly attack if hungry or threatened (which corresponds to option D), they would have used "when" in place of "if", like "Tigers and lions attack when they are hungry or threatened". But since they have used "if", that means they are talking about a possibility and not certainty. Hence, they mean C which says "If a lion or tiger is hungry or threatened, he may (or may not) attack"

Comment: @Rahul 1. As long as you are talking about English sentences that are to be transliterated into formulas like those in A-D, all contingency subordinators (*if*, when(ever), where(ever), once, …*) are equivalent. 2. To talk about possibility, you'd need the resources of [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic). 3. Even if possibility is allowed, it's not true that *if* expresses mere possibility only. *If you jump of the top of the skyscraper you will die* does not express mere possibility. 4. What *when(ever)* does stress is 'general recurrent contingency'.

Comment: And, 5. The questions about the difference between *If A then B* and *When A, B* in natural language should really be posed as a separate question. They have little to do with the present one. And in fact, there is already a question about that, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119426/if-when-in-this-example).

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot more than your answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your present purposes,**

*Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened*

is equivalent to

*If they are hungry or threatened, then tigers and lions attack*

(so 1. is correct),

which is (in your present context) equivalent to D.

Note that your purposes concern a very restricted setting, which is why J. Taylor says your question is off topic; it's not really about natural language. As far as more natural settings (i.e. not logic classes), see John Lawler's and Hellion's comments, above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a doubt, though. Can you always do that to an "if" statement? That is, write "A if B" as "if B then A"? What if the statement is "I'll go out if the weather is fine"? Writing it as "If the weather is fine, then I will go out" makes it sound like "if the weather is fine, then I HAVE to go out" but there is no such imperative in the first statement.

Comment: @Rahul Your teacher or assistant or text for the class in which this is a problem should be able to answer these kinds of subtle questions. Remember that these kinds of questions are about the truth of the statement so "If the weather is fine, then I will go out" implies "If the weather is fine, then I must go out, if the statement 'If the weather is fine, then I will go out,' is to be understood as true".

Comment: @Rahul As we all said, your setting is not that of natural language. The formal logic you use in the problems for this class does not have formal resources to talk about imperatives and so on (probably; check with your instructor). So yes, in the context of your class (probably; check with your instructor) both 'A if B' and 'if B then A' are equivalent to the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional), 'not-B or A'.

Comment: Okay. So the "absolute" (mathematical) approach is preferred as opposed to the ambiguous (natural language) approach if I'm understanding it correctly. Got it. Sadly, this question was not part of a class test or such, but was asked in an exam that is taken by around 100,000 graduate students every year for admissions to M.Tech in Computer Science & Engg., which I am also giving this year. Releasing official "keys" to the paper wasn't a thing the year this question was asked so we are left to guessing, though the overwhelming majority believes D to be the right answer so there's that.

Comment: @Rahul Still, the very fact that one of the answers A-D is supposed to be correct indicates that the setting is just like it would be for a logic class. This not about real lions and tigers, but about how in some contexts (math, computer science, certain branches of philisophy) one can transliterate back and forth betwen symbolic formulas and English sentences. The point is that this transliteration is purely formal, that is, it does not matter what the words 'tiger', 'lion', 'attacks', 'hungry', or 'threatened' mean. All this also shows why your question is arguably off topic for this site.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. I read too much into the question, thinking it is also testing for English (there's also a section in the paper for General Aptitude and English worth 15 marks/100) and used my GRE understanding of 'when' vs 'if' to solve what was purely a mathematical question. I'm glad we had this discussion though, thank you. John Lawler's comments were particularly eye-opening.